# Finding shapes inside aerial images

Tags: python, opencv, gis, feature-extraction

The problem I'm trying to approach is finding a certain shape from my own *shape library* inside a high resolution aerial image.

Right now, I'm obtaining a binary image containing the pixels of interest from my input image by running thresholding, morphological operations, DBSCAN obtaining an image as the following. [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DGMI.png)]

[image: Pixels of interest]

Then I'm using OpenCV's `matchShape` to test which of my shapes is the most similar. After getting the best match [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZpWR.png)], I'm trying to find where and how this shape is present in the original image, but I haven't been able to find a decent result using ORB.

[image: The matched shape]

In the end, I would like to get the location, scaling and rotation of the shape inside the image so I can then obtain a geojson containing the geometry of the shape but positioned as in the input image.

I am not sure whether this approach is correct, the best or how to proceed in order to achieve this end result, so if anyone could shed some light, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You could try log-polar FFT processing. See for example https://github.com/Smorodov/LogPolarFFTTemplateMatcher